# Custom server control sets properties to default on postback

Tags: asp.net, custom-server-controls

By following a tutorial aimed at creating a video player I adapted it to build a HTML5 range control. Here is my code:

```
namespace CustomServerControls
{
    [DefaultProperty("Text")]
    [ToolboxData("<{0}:Range runat=server ID=Range1></{0}:Range>")]
    public class Range : WebControl
    {
        public int Min { get; set; }
        public int Max { get; set; }
        public int Step { get; set; }
        public int Value { get; set; }

        protected override void RenderContents(HtmlTextWriter output)
        {
            output.AddAttribute(HtmlTextWriterAttribute.Id, this.ID);
            output.AddAttribute(HtmlTextWriterAttribute.Width, this.Width.ToString());
            output.AddAttribute(HtmlTextWriterAttribute.Height, this.Height.ToString());

            if (Min > Max)
                throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("Min", "The Min value cannot be greater than the Max Value.");

            if (Value > Max || Value < Min)
                throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("Value", Value,
                                                      "The Value attribute can not be less than the Min value or greater than the Max value");

            if (Min != 0)
                output.AddAttribute("min", Min.ToString());

            if (Max != 0)
                output.AddAttribute("max", Max.ToString());

            if (Step != 0)
                output.AddAttribute("step", Step.ToString());

            output.AddAttribute("value", Value.ToString());

            output.AddAttribute("type", "range");
            output.RenderBeginTag("input");
            output.RenderEndTag();

            base.RenderContents(output);
        }
    }  
}
```

As you can see, very simple, and it works as far as being able to set the individual properties.

If I do a post back to check what the current value is, the control resets its properties back to default (0). I imagine this is a viewstate issue. Does anyone see anything i'm missing from the above code to make this work properly?

**Edit:**

I noticed this markup is being rendered to the page:

```
<span id="Range1" style="display:inline-block;">
    <input id="Range1" min="1" max="100" value="5" type="range">
</span>
```

Which is obviously wrong, I don't want a span tag created, and the input control doesn't have a name. So when I postback I get no data from the control.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
[DefaultProperty("Value")]
[ToolboxData("<{0}:Range runat=server />")]
public class Range : WebControl, IPostBackDataHandler {

    private static readonly object mChangeEvent = new object();

    public Range() : base(HtmlTextWriterTag.Input) { }

    [Category("Events")]
    public event EventHandler Change {
        add { Events.AddHandler(mChangeEvent, value); }
        remove { Events.RemoveHandler(mChangeEvent, value); }
    }

    [DefaultValue(0)]
    public int Value {
        get { return (int?)ViewState["Value"] ?? 0; }
        set { ViewState["Value"] = value; }
    }

    protected override void AddAttributesToRender(HtmlTextWriter writer) {
        base.AddAttributesToRender(writer);

        // Add other attributes (Max, Step and value)

        writer.AddAttribute(HtmlTextWriterAttribute.Value, Value.ToString());
        writer.AddAttribute(HtmlTextWriterAttribute.Name, UniqueID);
        writer.AddAttribute(HtmlTextWriterAttribute.Type, "range");
    }

    protected virtual void OnChange(EventArgs e) {
        if (e == null) {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("e");
        }

        EventHandler handler = Events[mChangeEvent] as EventHandler;

        if (handler != null) {
            handler(this, e);
        }
    }

    #region [ IPostBackDataHandler Members ]

    public bool LoadPostData(string postDataKey, NameValueCollection postCollection) {
        int val;

        if (int.TryParse(postCollection[postDataKey], out val) && val != Value) {
            Value = val;
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }

    public void RaisePostDataChangedEvent() {
        OnChange(EventArgs.Empty);
    }

    #endregion

}
```

As far as @VinayC said you have to use ViewState and ControlState (For critical data) to persist your control's states. Also, you have to implement [IPostBackDataHandler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.ipostbackdatahandler.aspx) to restore the last value and raise the change event as you can see in the preceding example.

**Update**

```
[DefaultProperty("Value")]
[ToolboxData("<{0}:Range runat=server />")]
public class Range : WebControl, IPostBackEventHandler, IPostBackDataHandler {

    [Category("Behavior")]
    [DefaultValue(false)]
    public bool AutoPostBack {
        get { return (bool?)ViewState["AutoPostBack"] ?? false; }
        set { ViewState["AutoPostBack"] = value; }
    }

    protected override void OnPreRender(EventArgs e) {
        base.OnPreRender(e);

        if (!DesignMode && AutoPostBack) {

            string script = @"
var r = document.getElementById('{0}');

r.addEventListener('mousedown', function (e) {{
    this.oldValue = this.value;
}});

r.addEventListener('mouseup', function (e) {{
    if (this.oldValue !== this.value) {{
        {1};
    }}
}});";

            Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(
                this.GetType(),
                this.UniqueID,
                string.Format(script, this.ClientID, Page.ClientScript.GetPostBackEventReference(new PostBackOptions(this))),
                true);
        }
    }

    #region [ IPostBackEventHandler Members ]

    public void RaisePostBackEvent(string eventArgument) {
        // If you need to do somthing on postback, derive your control 
        // from IPostBackEventHandler interface.
    }

    #endregion

}
```

The above code illustrates how you can use [ClientScriptManager.GetPostBackEventReference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.clientscriptmanager.getpostbackeventreference.aspx) and [IPostBackEventHandler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev10.query?appId=Dev10IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k%28SYSTEM.WEB.UI.IPOSTBACKEVENTHANDLER%29;k%28IPOSTBACKEVENTHANDLER%29;k%28TargetFrameworkMoniker-%22.NETFRAMEWORK,VERSION=V4.0%22%29;k%28DevLang-CSHARP%29&rd=true) to implement a simple AutoPostback for your Range control.

Comment: can you show me or link me to a web site explaining how I would implement auto post back for this control? I've searched and haven't found what i'm looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Issue is that your properties (`Min`, `Max`, `Step`, `Value`) are backed by instance fields - in ASP.NET, every page and every control instance on it gets re-created when page posts back. So every time, those properties will have default values (or values that you may set at design time) - in order to retain those values over post-back, you need to back your properties using view-state. For example:

```
public int Min 
{ 
   get
   {
       var value = ViewState["Min"];
       return null != value ? (int)value : 0;
   }
   set { ViewState["Min"] = value; }
}
```

Because view-state can be disabled, control authors may also use control state to back up their **important** properties (that are essential for control to work) - for using control state, you need override [LoadControlState](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.loadcontrolstate.aspx) and [SaveControlState](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.savecontrolstate.aspx) methods.

For example (using control state):

```
public int Min { get; set; }
public int Max { get; set; }
public int Step { get; set; }
public int Value { get; set; }

protected override void OnInit(EventArgs e) 
{
    Page.RegisterRequiresControlState(this); // must for using control state
    base.OnInit(e);
}

protected override object SaveControlState() 
{
    return new int[] { Min, Max, Step, Value };
}

protected override void LoadControlState(object state) 
{
    var values = state as int[];
    if (null != values) 
    {
       Min = values[0]; Max = values[1];
       Step = values[2]; Value = values[3];
    }
}
```